# Combine two images using PHP GD

Tags: php, image, gd, watermark

I am trying to create an image which will have my image A (uploaded image) and image B (my watermark image). My problem is that I am not getting the proper way to extend the size of image from the bottom which will be created with image A and B.

My code is -

```
$img_width=imagesx($img);
$img_height=imagesy($img);
$watermark=imagecreatefrompng($watermark);
$watermark_width=imagesx($watermark);
$watermark_height=imagesy($watermark);

$image=imagecreatetruecolor($img_width, $img_height+35);
imagealphablending($image, false);
$dest_x=$img_width-$watermark_width;
$dest_y=$img_height-$watermark_height+20;

imagecopy($img, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0,$watermark_width, $watermark_height);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
imagejpeg($img, $config['pdir']."/t/l-".$thepp, 90);
}
```

What I am getting with this code is -

[Results http://www.9gag.in/pdata/t/l-76.jpg](http://www.9gag.in/pdata/t/l-76.jpg)

You can see the watermark image is not totally merged with the image I want to create. I want an extended area in the destination image where the watermark will be fitted properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you writes :

```
$dest_y=$img_height-$watermark_height+20;
```

I guess you really want :

```
$dest_y=$img_height-$watermark_height-20;
```

Y = 0 at the top of your image, so the more bottom you go, the more high is your height.